# How can I be informed of the presence of streets closed to cars during some time of the day?

Tags: online-resources, automobiles, maps

Some streets are closed to cars during some time of the day, e.g. when more pedestrians are expected to frequent the street or when the tide is up. How can I be informed of the existence of such streets when I am in a given location nearby? E.g., is there any database of such streets?

I'm interested in streets that are commonly frequented, not tiny streets in remote villages. I'm looking for a solution that is as generic as possible, e.g. maybe Google Maps indicate such closures, or some database cover a fair percentage of the most frequented streets.

Comment: this is not generally answerable. Even if there is a database it won't cover the whole world, or towns and villages of arbitrary small size in the area it does cover. Some places might have signs on the street itself and nothing else; others might not even have that. The question invites list answers that are all as good or bad as each other.

Comment: @KateGregory "The question invites list answers" no, I'm looking for a solution that is as generic as possible, e.g. maybe Google Maps indicate such closures, or some database cover a fair percentage of the most frequented streets.

Comment: the issue with Google Maps is that it **might** show you that a street is closed **now**. That is not the same as showing that it is closed every Sunday afternoon, which appears to be your request. Can you clarify? How far away in space and time do you want to know?

Comment: @KateGregory I took Google Maps as an example, but perhaps some other mapping program may be more explicit about street closing times. I'm just interested in the new few days. as for the space, I'm mostly interested in the US, but I'm curious about other countries since sometimes I go outside the US.

Comment: you'll have to look at crowd sourcing this, maybe waze ? even if coutries/region/cities have open sourced that information, each will have its own format.

Comment: A lot of this data is captured on OpenStreetMap, so the crowdsourcing @Max suggests has already been done.  I'm pretty certain [Overpass Turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/) queries for `way["highway"]` combined with the presence of an `opening_hours` tag would do this (NB this is the UK legalise sense of highway, so refers to public roads in general).  I don't use Overpass Turbo very often so have to figure it out every time, but I can think of a test case or two, and may have a play if I get the chance (unlikely until I finish building my new home PC)

Comment: Voting to reopen, as there *is* a global database (@KateGregory) that supports this information. [It's been discussed in OpenStreetMap help](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/24090/how-can-i-set-up-a-street-to-be-only-accessible-on-week-days) but my previous comment had an error - it's not opening hours but [conditional restrictions](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Conditional_restrictions).

Comment: Please be aware that OpenStreetMap is community edited, so while for some areas the data will be very up-to-date (better than "official" datasets), other areas may be terribly out-of-date.  Just depends on how many people update the data in the different areas.  Large cities are usually pretty good

Comment: @Midavalo This shows the question is answerable and a good fit for this site.

Comment: I remember some 'funny' closures in the west of Greater London, where a local road was closed when the high tide reached the area, all the way through London. It was mostly used to reach a parking space and according to the locals they had cars in water to the roof at times.

Comment: _Generally_ Waze will know about road closures for events. I believe it now also supports date/time-based closures and/or direction restrictions. However, I don' think that's really searchable in the way @FranckDernoncourt sounds like he's looking for it. If he's trying to get somewhere, Waze will route him with those closures in mind, though.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I disagree, it's about as good/bad as suggesting Wikipedia as an answer.  To me this question can't have one authoritative answer, so would lead to list answers as suggested by @ KateGregory

Comment: @Midavalo  What would a list answer contain?